# PHP Date incorrect with a format like YYYY/DD/MM

Tags: php, date

When I insert it into my database, it works :

```
$time = strtotime('1' . '/' . 10 . '/' . '2015');
$res = date('y-n-d',$time);
```

BUT when I insert it into my databse, it doesn't :

```
$time = strtotime('10' . '/' . 10 . '/' . '2015');
$res = date('y-n-d',$time);
```

This code insert in my database the 1970-01-01 default date...

The only change is the length of the day. I tried to change the format of the date, like Y-m-d, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: when you insert and when you insert??)))

Comment: Not sure to understand your sentence ^^

Comment: Make it clear about you problem.

Comment: You cannot insert it into your database using the second way?

Comment: what format is your database field?

Comment: format of your column in the database?

Comment: Ok, first, I'm using PDO to insert in my DB. I'm doing something like this : $time = strtotime('10' . '/' . 10 . '/' . '2015');
$res = date('y-n-d',$time); $stmt = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO Table(time) VALUES(?); $stmt->bindParam(1,$time); $stmt->execute()

Comment: So what???????????????

Comment: In my DB this is a Date type

Comment: Why don't you use "INSERT INTO `table` VALUES( NOW() )"?

Comment: @sgtBOSE When I insert, it doesn't work and inserts 1970-01-01 default

Comment: @Akar now() will return the actual date right ? I don't want it :)

Comment: Add the issue to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DateTime` interface -

```
$time = new DateTime('10' . '/' . 10 . '/' . '2015');
echo $res = $time->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: So my column should be DateTime type ?

Comment: Is it `Date` for now??

Comment: Yes, I don't know the difference between both

Comment: It will work in both cases. Only for `DateTime` the time part will be `00:00:00`

Comment: I think it could work, but I get this error message : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string ...

Comment: When I write '10' . '/' etc... it works, but I would like to concat $time with other variables. Like this :  $dateParam = $tabDate[0] . '/' . $idMonth . '/' . '2015'; $time = new DateTime($dateParam); But types seem to be uncompatible

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$unixDate='01/01/1900';$differenceValue = strtotime($time)- strtotime($unixDate);
```

insert $differenceValue to Database.

Comment: $time='1/10/2015';The Date which you want to insert.

Comment: And unixDate is a constant that we substract to the $time ?

Answer (score 0):

Use it in following way...

```
$time = date("d-m-Y", strtotime('1/10/2015'));
$res = date("Y-m-d", $time);
```

OR

```
$date = date_create('1/10/2015');
$res = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were trying to insert a timestamp (integer) into a DATE field. If your db is MySQL and your using DATETIME type, then you could use this php date format:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

Also, I'd suggest using new DateTime() as @sgtBose mentioned, as you might get unexpected results from strtotime() in different locales.